# Reverse external array in assembly using swapping method - x86 MASM

Tags: c++, arrays, assembly, masm

I am working on a project where we need to pass an array of type **char** as a parameter and reverse the array. I feel like I am very close to getting it done, but I am stuck on the actual swapping process.

For my swapping function in my .asm, I used the same method I would in c++ (use an unused register as a temp, then swap the front and the back.) What I am not understanding is how would I go about changing the actual content at that address. I assumed performing the following would "change" the content at the destination address:

```
mov eax,[edx]
```

However, this did not work as planned. After I ran a for loop to iterate through the array again, everything stayed the same.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be great. I have provided the code below with as much comments as I could provide.

Also, I am doing all this in a single .asm file; however, my professor wants me to have 3 separate .asm document for each of the following functions: swap, reverse, and getLength. I tried to include the other 2 .asm document in the reverse.asm, but it kept giving me an error.

Assembly Code Starts:

```
.686
.model flat

.code

_reverse PROC 
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp ;Have ebp point to esp

    mov ebx,[ebp+8] ;Point to beginning of array
    mov eax,ebx
    mov edx,1
    mov ecx,0
    mov edi,0
    jmp getLength

getLength:
    cmp ebp, 0          ;Counter to iterate until needed to stop
    je setup

    add ecx,1
    mov ebp,[ebx+edx]
    add edx,1
    jmp getLength

setup:                  ;This is to set up the numbers correctly and get array length divided by 2
    mov esi,ecx
    mov edx,0
    mov eax,ecx
    mov ecx,2
    div ecx

    mov ecx,eax
    add ecx,edx         ;Set up ecx(Length of string) correctly by adding modulo if odd length string
    mov eax,ebx
    dec esi

    jmp reverse

reverse:                ;I started the reverse function by using a counter to iterate through length / 2
    cmp edi, ecx
    je allDone

    mov ebx,eax         ;Set ebx to the beginning of array
    mov edx,eax         ;Set edx to the beginning of array
    add ebx,edi         ;Move ebx to correct index to perform swap
    add edx,esi         ;Move edx to the back at the correct index

    jmp swap            ;Invoke swap function

swap:
    mov ebp,ebx         ;Move value to temp
    mov ebx,[edx]       ;Swap the back end value to the front
    mov edx,[edx]       ;Move temp to back

    inc edi             ;Increment to move up one index to set up next swap
    dec esi             ;Decrement to move back one  index to set up for next swap

    jmp reverse         ;Jump back to reverse to setup next index swapping

allDone:
    pop ebp
    ret

_reverse ENDP

END
```

C++ Code starts:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

extern "C" char reverse(char*);

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 20;
    char str1[SIZE] = { NULL };

    cout << "Please enter a string: ";
    cin >> str1;

    cout << "Your string is: ";

    for (int i = 0; str1[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        cout << str1[i];
    }

    cout << "." << endl;

    reverse(str1);

    cout << "Your string in reverse is: ";

    for (int i = 0; str1[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        cout << str1[i];
    }

    cout << "." << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using Intel assembly syntax. In that syntax the first operand is the destination and the second is the source but not visa versa.

Comment: Since I was confused about the whole bracket (i.e [edx]), I assumed that whatever is within [edx] would replace the content of ebx (which currently has the address of the first index).

For example in C++ (since I am more familier with C++):

int i = 25;
int *p = &i;
*p = 35;

Is this what is happening when I perform mov ebx,[edx] ??

Comment: In this case the 32 bits of the memory pointed by `edx` will be copied to `ebx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mov eax,[edx]` (assuming intel syntax) places the 32 bits found in memory at address edx into eax. I.e, this code *retrieves* data from a memory location. If you'd like to write to a mem location, you need to reverse this, i.e `mov [edx], eax`

After playing with some 16 bit code overnight for sorting, I've the following two functions that may be of use. Obviously, you can't copy/paste them - you'll have to study it. However, you'll notice that it is able to swap items of arbitrary size. Perfect for swapping elements that are structures of some type.

```
; copies cx bytes from ds:si to es:di
copyBytes:
    shr     cx, 1
    jnc     .swapCopy1Loop
    movsb
.swapCopy1Loop:
    shr     cx, 1
    jnc     .swapCopy2Loop
    movsw
.swapCopy2Loop:
    rep     movsd
    ret

;               bp+0        bp+2   bp+4
;void swap(void *ptr1, void *ptr2, int dataSizeBytes)
swapElems:
    push    bp
    mov     bp, sp
    add     bp, 4
    push    di
    push    si
    push    es

    mov     ax, ds
    mov     es, ax

    sub     sp, [bp+4]      ; allocate dataSizeBytes on the stack, starting at bp-6 - dataSizeBytes

    mov     di, sp
    mov     si, [bp+0]
    mov     cx, [bp+4]
    call    copyBytes

    mov     si, [bp+2]
    mov     di, [bp+0]
    mov     cx, [bp+4]
    call    copyBytes

    mov     si, sp
    mov     di, [bp+2]
    mov     cx, [bp+4]
    call    copyBytes

    add     sp, [bp+4]

    pop     es
    pop     si
    pop     di
    pop     bp
    ret     2 * 3
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Since this is basically my first time working with assembly, I am not too familiar with some of the syntax. Since in class he only taught us how to push ebp into the stack, I don't really understand why we need to push the other register into the stack. I will look around online for more information, but if the answer is short, can you please clarify? Thank you!

Comment: That's okay. I can only see your code only use `push` once, so I'm assuming you're wondering about why I pushed the other registers onto the stack. This is so that we can restore their original values after we've finished using them and can leave them in whatever state they were in when our function was called. Take for instance `copyBytes` - this function doesn't push/pop any of its registers, so when it's finished the CX, SI and DI registers have all changed - I know that the function that calls `copyBytes` doesn't rely on these registers remaining unchanged, so I didn't bother to save them.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I messed around with it again and got it to work somewhat. It was able to copy the last letter to the front of the array, but the rest is just junk. I looked more into it and I believe I understand the issue. Since I am performing mov eax,[ebx], it is actually copying 4 bytes. My goal here is to copy a single byte at that location since it is a char. How would I go about just coping 1 byte at that location?

Comment: Funnily enough, you just have to use a smaller register as your `tmp` variable. E.g, `mov al, [edx]` for 1 byte, `mov ax, [edx]` for 2 bytes and `mov eax, [edx]` for 4 bytes. So, if you have two byte-sized elements to swap, and edx points to elem1, while ebx points to elem2, you could just do this: `mov al, [edx]`, `mov ah, [ebx]`, `mov [edx], ah`, `mov [ebx], al`

Comment: What are the chances!! I actually just figured that out only a few minutes ago and posted an answer. After I switched to smaller registers, it worked right away. Thanks for your help through this process! I will mark yours as answer as it was also answered in the comments.

Comment: Fantastic! Deriving the answer yourself is by far the best outcome, I think. I'm far more interested in teaching people to fish than I am in giving them fish, even if the latter requires less time & effort on my part. ;)

Answer (score 2):

So after many more hours of tinkering and looking around, I was finally able to figure out how to properly copy over a byte. I will post my .asm code below with comments if anybody needs it for future reference.

I was actually moving the content of the current address into a 32 bit registers. After I changed it from **mov ebx,[eax]** to **mov bl,[eax]**, it copied the value correctly.

I will only post the code that I was having difficulty with so I do not give away the entire project for other students.

ASM Code Below:

```
swap:
mov bl,[edx]        ;Uses bl since we are trying to copy a 1 byte char value
mov bh,[eax]        ;Uses bh since we are trying to copy a 1 byte char value

mov [edx],bh        ;Passing the value to the end of the array
mov [eax],bl        ;Passing the value to the beginning of the array

inc eax             ;Moving the array one index forward
dec edx             ;Moving the array one index backwards

dec ecx             ;Decreasing the counter by one to continue loop as needed

jmp reverse         ;Jump back to reverse to check if additional swap is needed
```

Thanks for everyone that helped.

Comment: Unless you're really short of registers, you'll sometimes see performance penalties from using different parts of the same register (bl and bh), instead of two different registers (like al and dl).  Partial-registers create false dependencies on some CPUs.  And if you can without wasting mov instructions, use esi to hold a source pointer, and edi to hold a dest pointer.  That's just a standard convention based on the names of the registers, and only actually matters if you want to use `rep movs` or something that implicitly uses esi and edi as pointers.

Comment: also, put a conditional branch at the bottom of your loop if you can.  Like `dec ecx / jnz swap`.  Also, you could move 4 bytes at a time by doing a 4B load and using `bswap` to reverse the order of those 4 bytes before storing again.  But then you'd need to handle the last less-than-4 bytes with a special case at the end.  Similarly, you could do 16B at a time with SSSE3 `pshufb` (byte-shuffle).

Comment: See the links at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more docs, esp. Agner Fog's docs for learning to write *good* asm once you learn the basics.

Comment: Hello Peter, Thanks for the link. I will look more into this right now to get a better grasp of things.